# onclick url undefined Angular js

Tags: php, html, angularjs

The list of albums displayed, but I want to be able to click on an album in the table and it shows a list of tracks on the same page. When I do this the url says  "http://localhost/cm0665-assignment/#/album/undefined".

I think it has something to do with the 'albumcode'. But not sure what to do.

javascript

```
$scope.selectedalbum = {};
$scope.selectAlbum = function ($event, album){
     $scope.selectedAlbum = album;
     $location.path('/album/' + album.albumCode);
};
```

html

```
<table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="album in albums"
        data-ng-click="selectAlbum($event, album)"
        data-ng-class="{'selected':selectedAlbum.albumCode===album.album_id}"
        style="cursor: pointer;">
        <td>{{album.album_id}}</td><td>{{album.Name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it `albumCode` or `album_id`? You seem to be using the two interchangeably.

Comment: @Lex so does it have to be the same ? i think it would be album_id because that's in the sql statement in my php file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "does it have to be the same", but I am guessing since you are getting `undefined` for `album.albumCode` that it does not exist on your `album` object.

Comment: Is the selected class added after clicking on an album? If not, either the album parameter passed in the function is not good or it does not contain the `albumCode` parameter

Comment: try doing `console.log(album)` inside `$scope.selectAlbum` function to  check what are the keys available in the album object. Then you will know if it is `albumCode or album_id`